# Unable to find arduino on device manager

Tags: arduino-uno, windows

I have just got a new Arduino robot for Christmas and I have plugged my robot into my computer and I have read the instructions from the manual that the robot was provided with and told me to go to the device manager in the control panel and look under unknown devices, unfortunately I was unable to find it. However I looked under ports and I found that there were 3 ports, I eventually found out that if I took the Arduino plug in and out of my PC that port COM5 was the Arduino, the problem I am having now is to know how to get this port to recognise my Arduino

[image]

one error that always comes up when trying to upload the code onto COM5 is this:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa1
```

This is what the arduino looks like
[image]

Link for where I brought the arduino kit from:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/ELEGOO-Tracking-Ultrasonic-Intelligent-Educational/dp/B01M6YHRJ4/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=elegoo+robot&qid=1577982862&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyVjVXTk9VMDlUTTg1JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjc4NjYwOEVGNEoxM1Y0QzIwJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA4OTA1NzAzTTNBVFJMV09aVjJRJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==

[image]

This is what shows up on the arduino IDE when I select COM5 (which should be my arduino)

Comment: @jsotola how come when I try to load it onto my arduino it comes up with the error: (shown above)

Comment: what device do you have? ... add a link to your post .... upvote for adding info about avrdude to the post instead of putting in comments

Comment: Try a few random things. Unplug your arduino and reboot your computer. Plug it back in before starting the Arduino interface, look in the menu to be sure the right Arduino device is selected. Look for the serial port and be sure the right one is selected - it might have changed.

Comment: It is likely that this is a driver issue. I have encountered similar errors, and by updating/installing the drivers, it fixes itself

Answer (score 1):

It seems your computer recognize the serial port of the Arduino device, but doesn't know how to 'talk to it'.

In most USB to TTL devices (that are included in Arduino and ESP8266 boards) you need to install their driver (like CH341 driver) BEFORE you plug in your device.

Please try to find/identify the 'USB to Serial' chip you have on the board, and install its drivers.

Good Luck!

Comment: I am only a teenager and do not have much knowledge on arduino itself. Can you possibly guide me on how I can do this please.

Comment: You're totally welcome (and after I upvoted your question, you have upvote privileges too...). Let's start by finding the exact model number of the Arduino you have. Can you put a link to where it was bought? or a picture of the board itself?

Comment: I can firstly start off by saying that it is an Arduino Uno. I got it as a christmas present, so I am not 100% sure about it fully.(A picture of the arduino is shown above). The links for where I brought it from is also shown above as well

Comment: sorry if my webcam is not very clear

Comment: Good you've updated more details about the board. The picture is good. This is not a solution, but just found this: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=521632.0 about the board you're using. Also - This search brings many answers and tutorials that make sense to me: https://www.google.com/search?q=elegoo+uno+r3+usb+driver . Would you try to look into this available information and update us what makes sense to you? GoodLuck!

Comment: Oh yeah, there was one more thing I forgot to mention was that the arduino IDE does see COM5 but doesn't see it as being an arduino though. (shown above)

Comment: Totally understood. It was clear from your first screen capture, and my answer stays the same. Please make some more investigation using the resources I've mentioned, and let's know what have you discovered.